# Postgress and PHP "Ident authentication failed for user"

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, yii, centos

On my local server (Ubuntu 14.04) all work ok. But on test server (Centos) i cannot connect from PHP (Yii 1.1) to my database.
On both servers i used same dump, user name, password, postgres and php code versions.

On local server apache. On Test nginx.

> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[08006] [7]
>   FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "tripinsu"

pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Comment: Not really a programming question, but ... is your postgres configured to actually LISTEN to the local interfaces on your centos box?  **grep listen_addresses /path/to/postgresql.conf**

Comment: "#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;" Also I tried remove comments and change to "*". Not work

Comment: `ident` authentication means the OS user must have the same login as the database user. The error message reports failure to pass this test. `ident` is generally not adequate for a web server, use a different authentication scheme such as `md5`.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed. Not sure what i changed. I just copy my correct config from ubuntu.

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I hope this help somebody else