# Connect DBeaver to localhost Postgre on linux

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, opensuse

I'm trying to connect dbeaver to postgresql using linux.

This is the setup:

- OpenSuse tumbleweed, full update to the current date
- Dbeaver 23.1.5
- Postgresql 15-2.9

I installed postgresql from suse repositories then did the steps described into [opensuse PostgreSQL](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:PostgreSQL) and ended with a newly created user.
I have gotten the Dbeaver Community zipped from [here](https://dbeaver.io/download/), unzipped it at a desired location and run it.

Tried to login through Dbeaver with this connection settings:

- connected by Host
- localhost
- port 5432
- database postgres

> error: Ident authentication failed for user

Tried searching for a solution, got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754357/postgress-and-php-ident-authentication-failed-for-user), md5 seemed a bit outdated so I searched more after reading the content inside **pg_hba.conf** and set it to scram-sha-256 and got the file to look like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             newuser                                 scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             newuser       127.0.0.1/32              scram-sha-256
host    all             newuser       localhost                 scram-sha-256
host    all             postgres      127.0.0.1/32              ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             newuser       ::1/128                   scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
```

Also, uncommented `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` at **postgresql.conf**.
On command-line, did:

```
postgres=# drop user newuser
```

Then:

```
postgres-# create role newuser with encrypted password 'somepassword'
```

Exited postgres, restarted service, executed command `psql -U newuser -h localhost -W`...
Got:

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user

Got back into psql, did `create database testdatabase with owner newuser encoding = 'UTF16' tablespace = pg_default`

Got out and tried again with the following: `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U newuser -f a.sql testdatabase` Same error.

Before messing around too much and having to deal with a lot of cleanup, and not having found any question that suits my situation, do anyone know what is missing here? Do I need to create a new user on system level and map it to the database user?

The right answer will explain how to connect to postgres using Dbeaver on localhost and containing all the steps necessary. Alternatively, connecting through pgadmin at localhost might help me understand next steps, but I will only validate this if steps given doesn't result into one of the error above.

I have read the following questions and sources that didn't fix my situation:

- [FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://tecadmin.net/fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/)
- [error: Ident authentication failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410006/error-ident-authentication-failed-for-user)
- [How to configure postgresql for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471571/how-to-configure-postgresql-for-the-first-time)
- [How to Generate SCRAM-SHA-256 to Create Postgres 13 User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400120/how-to-generate-scram-sha-256-to-create-postgres-13-user)
- [How can I connect to a database as another user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180667/how-can-i-connect-to-a-database-as-another-user)